# why binding in javafx doesn't work?and how can i fix it?

Tags: java, javafx, bind

hi i am new in javafx and i have an issue and that is :

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    setImages();
    stagged.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("media.png")));
    handleSound();
    playlist.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            handlePlaying(newValue.intValue());
            playlist.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();;
        }
    });
    mediaview.fitWidthProperty().bind(stack.widthProperty());
    mediaview.fitHeightProperty().bind(stack.heightProperty());
    volume.setValue(100);
    // TODO
}
```

when i change my size of scene and stage and hence stack it correctly get fullscreen at a first place but after that when i resize it and small it my media (and stack !!)stay big and until my program is running it will stay big and when i resize it i see this crrectly! how can i fix this and more important why it is happening?
thank you in advance

Comment: The code you posted has very little to do with your question.  You may wish to edit the question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead.

Comment: i bind it in the bottom of my code and i use fx scene builder2 so i really didn't add stack myself and it is a stack pane